# Is it possible to segregate dependencies for different variant android based on flavour

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

**What I Have** :

- I have a project where I have not of dependencies in app-level gradle
- I have two variants free and paid

**What I want to do**:
I am trying to segregate the dependencies so that some I can add for free variant and other for paid

---

**my app level gradle**

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    
    
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.cnx.kneurateach"
            vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
            minSdkVersion 24
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode generateVersionCode()
            versionName generateVersionName()
            
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
                shrinkResources true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                //signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            }
    
    
            debug {
                minifyEnabled false
                shrinkResources false
                debuggable true
            }
        }
    
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    
        // Specifies one flavor dimension.
        flavorDimensions "common"
        productFlavors {
            freee {
                
            }
            paid {
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    
    dependencies {

        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '.aar'])
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlinVersion"
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'


        //Below one only for paid
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    
       
    }
```